# swipe thumbnail for preview jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin with hover on desktop and swipe support on mobile.

Basically what I need is when you swipe (mobile)/hover (desktop) on a thumbnail images start rotate. I've seen it a lot on adult streaming websites...

do you know any plugins or ways I can achieve this effect?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one here http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick . It has a lot of options and support mobile browsers.